# How to assign a event to another event?

Tags: c#, winforms, events

I am in a need of copying the properties and events data to another instance. But the events could not be copied.

Is there any way, the events can be assigned to another event of an instance?

I have the below structure,

Class EventAssign contains some properties and event called "Changed" and this changed event of EventAssign and its properties can be modified and event can be subscribed.

For my purpose, i am duplicating the created instance of EventAssign with its properties and its events like below,

```
public EventAssign CreateDuplicate(EventAssign event)
{
    EventAssign eventAssign = new EventAssign();
    eventAssign properties = event properties
    // and here i want to copy the events**
    return eventAssign;
}
```

Any one please let me know, how to achieve this scenario.

Comment: No, you can't copy the handles of a regular event, this is by design and for security reasons. Why don't you include a couple of details about **why** you want to do this? Whatever you are doing there is certainly a better way. Possibly related: [The XY-Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer - I need to copy the events because i use these for my child controls which is also in need of subscribing these events.

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you don't use the same instance? I don't see how copying existing events of other instances would help you in any way.

Answer (score 2):

There is high chance that you should not be doing that, but if you really want - you can use reflection. Regular event (without custom add\remove) is a wrapper around field containing delegate which is invoked when event is raised. You need to copy that field. Sample code:

```
public class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        var target = new EventAssign
        {
            Prop = "test"
        };
        target.Changed += (sender, args) =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Invoked!");
        };
        var copy = Copy(target);
        target.InvokeChanged();
        // handler was copied too, so invoking event on copy
        // will also run handler above
        copy.InvokeChanged();
    }

    static EventAssign Copy(EventAssign target) {
        var copy = new EventAssign();
        copy.Prop = target.Prop;
        // get all events via reflection
        var publicEvents = typeof(EventAssign).GetEvents(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public);
        foreach (var ev in publicEvents) {
            // each "regular" event (without custom add\remove) should have
            // a backing field with the same name
            var evField = typeof(EventAssign).GetField(ev.Name, BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
            if (evField == null || evField.FieldType != ev.EventHandlerType)
                continue;
            // copy this field value
            evField.SetValue(copy, evField.GetValue(target));
        }
        return copy;
    }
}

class EventAssign {
    public string Prop { get; set; }
    public event EventHandler Changed;

    public void InvokeChanged() {
        Changed?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}
```

Comment: *"There is high chance that you should not be doing that"* A **very** high chance.